# Mirage + JSONAPI Array

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli-mirage

I have a basic api that is setup like so...

```
/api/v1/logs/
/api/v1/logs/type1-logs
/api/v1/logs/type2-logs
/api/v1/logs/type3-logs
```

They each only support GET, and if the user makes a request to /api/v1/logs they should be getting all of the logs.

I have the factories, and scenarios setup in Mirage, but I'm unsure how to actually return an array of different types.

My current config.js is causing ember to complain about an undefined resource type.

```
  this.get('/logs', function(db, request) {
    let data = {
      data: [
        db.type1Logs,
        db.type2Logs,
        db.type3Logs
      ]
    };
    return data;
  });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you have a chance to try the answer I provided?

Answer (score 0):

What is returned from a typical route definition (which returns multiple data) in mirage's config.js is of type [Collection](https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage/blob/master/addon/orm/collection.js). This means you need to return a collection. So sth. similar to the following should work:

```
import { Collection } from 'ember-cli-mirage';

export default function() {
    this.get('/logs', function(db, request) {
        let models = Ember.A();
        models.pushObjects(db.type1Logs.all().models);
        models.pushObjects(db.type2Logs.all().models);
        models.pushObjects(db.type3Logs.all().models);

        return new Collection('log', models);
    });
}
```

I initially misunderstood your problem and took a different approach of creating all the logs and filtering for types and created the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/e2f81a5a78d7c5e85c0d7522eaa36b57?openFiles=mirage.config.js%2C&route=%2Ftype2-type3-merged) for you. But then I realized you created different data for each type and what you need is just merging all of them. Then I decided to add type2 and type3 logs merged to the twiddle I prepared. You can see an example of the code I provided above in action within `mirage/config.js` under `this.get('/logs/type2type3-logs', function(schema){....}` definition. I hope this will help you.